# FLUTTER: Unable to load asset: images/diamond.png

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec.yaml

I know this question has been asked, I looked through all of them and couldn't find a fix for my code.

This is the pubspec yaml, I think that where I might have the error

```
name: i_am_rich
description: fuck this shit
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
```

and this is the dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('Shine bright like a'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/diamond.png'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

I tried fixing the indentations on the `pubspec.yaml`, both manually and with tab, and a bunch of stuff from youtube videos, even the course I'm taking (not very good honestly), been trying to fix this for HOURS please help.

Comment: i just realized i have no clue how to use stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

first in your pupspect yamel

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - assets/images/
  - assets/logo/
```

then refer to it like this:

```
                          icon: Image.asset(
                            "assets/logo/google_logo.png",
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            width: 24,
                          ),
```

dont forgot to create an assets folder like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Creating the assets folder and updating the pubspec.yaml fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

= Go to Terminal.  and write these commands. "flutter clean " then " flutter pub get " sometimes flutter is like this. and make sure the image file is located in the root of project like the above person's answer and not inside lib.

Comment: I'm fairly new to flutter and android studio, could you point me out where the terminal is?

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage(
            "images/diamond.png",
          ),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```